# Avoid flickering in transparent control while runtime themes are enabled

Tags: delphi, vcl, flicker

My control is a `TCustomControl` descendant where all the contents is painted with GDI+ in the overridden `Paint` method.

Everything is fine when

```
DoubleBuffered := True;
ParentBackground := False;
```

and I erase control's background in `Paint` method with

```
g := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
g.Clear(MakeColor(70, 70, 70));
```

Now I would like to make a transparent background in the areas where I am not painting.

So, I commented the `g.Clear` out and made

```
ParentBackground := True;
```

in constructor.

When runtime themes are off it is enough to set `DoubleBuffered` of parent control to `True` in order to avoid flickering, but with runtime themes this does not help any more.

Below is an excerpt from `TWinControl` code with a marked line that causes flickering:

```
procedure TWinControl.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  if StyleServices.Enabled and Assigned(Parent) and (csParentBackground in FControlStyle) then
  begin
    { Get the parent to draw its background into the control's background. }
    if Parent.DoubleBuffered then
      PerformEraseBackground(Self, Message.DC) //It flickers here!!!!!
    else
      StyleServices.DrawParentBackground(Handle, Message.DC, nil, False);
  end
  else
  begin
    { Only erase background if we're not doublebuffering or painting to memory. }
    if not FDoubleBuffered or
{$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
       (Message.OriginalMessage.WParam = Message.OriginalMessage.LParam) then
{$ELSE}
       (TMessage(Message).wParam = WPARAM(TMessage(Message).lParam)) then
{$ENDIF}
      FillRect(Message.DC, ClientRect, FBrush.Handle);
  end;
  Message.Result := 1;
end;
```

Are there any solutions to that?

Comment: Why do you have `DoubleBuffered` set to `True`?

Comment: I think it is likely possible to resolve the flickering without setting `DoubleBuffered` to `True`. That's been the route I have always taken to resolve flickering VCL controls.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But status bars and list view controls often require double buffering, or you get horrible visual artefacts (at least on most Swedish PCs I have seen).

Comment: @Paul: And don't invalidate parts that don't need to be repainted.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand list view and status bar are indeed exceptions to the rule.

Comment: So you can change the behavior by handling WM_ERASEBKGND yourself, no?

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in `TWinControl.WMEraseBkgnd` method. It should **always** skip erasing background for double buffered controls when control is not painting in memory.

You can override `WMEraseBkgnd` behavior in your own control, or patch `TWinControl.WMEraseBkgnd` to apply following fix for all controls.

```
  TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  protected
  ...
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  ...

procedure TMyControl.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd);
begin
{ Only erase background if we're not doublebuffering or painting to memory. }
  if not FDoubleBuffered or
{$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
    (Message.OriginalMessage.WParam = Message.OriginalMessage.LParam) then
{$ELSE}
    (TMessage(Message).WParam = WParam(TMessage(Message).LParam)) then
{$ENDIF}
    begin
      if StyleServices.Enabled and Assigned(Parent) and (csParentBackground in ControlStyle) then
        begin
          if Parent.DoubleBuffered then
            PerformEraseBackground(Self, Message.DC)
          else
            StyleServices.DrawParentBackground(Handle, Message.DC, nil, False);
        end
      else
        FillRect(Message.DC, ClientRect, Brush.Handle);
    end;
  Message.Result := 1;
end;
```

Issue is reported as [RSP-24415](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24415)